# Script to edit .csv files without opening them

Tags: csv, scripting, edit

I am looking for a way to edit .csv files without opening them if that is possible?
I have multiple .csv files that I am interested in the data between 2 separate times.  I am looking to delete all rows of the files before a certain time and all rows after a certain time.  The time is just a 6 digit number, example 114530.  The time value is located in the 6th column/field of the .csv file, the format of the time is hhmmss.

So say I have hours worth of data in multiple .csv files but for this instance I am only interested in the data of the files between 114530 and 163000.  Is there a way to do this.  I am not a programmer but have had some exposure to it at an basic/entry user level.

Comment: Without programming experience, I suggest using Notepad++ or similar text reader that handles large files gracefully and allow you to seek to the timestamp quickly with it's rich search features.

Answer (score 0):

**$ cat testTimeReplace.csv**

ba,blaba,bla,,,,,,

foo,foff,foo,,,,,,

one,t,th,f,f,114530,sev,,

bla,blaba,,,,,,,

bla,vv,vv,bla,vv,vv,bla,vv,vv

one,t,th,f,f,163000,,,

ba,blaba,bla,ba,blaba,bla,ba,blaba,bla

foo,foff,foo,foo,foff,foo,foo,foff,foom

**========== command to extract data between 114530 & 163000 =========**

$ **sed '1,/114530/d;/163000/,$d' testTimeReplace.csv**